# How do I make LLVM actually inline anything?

Tags: compilers, llvm, inlining

I've been working on a draft of a Trilangle compiler using LLVM. Out of curiosity, I took the generated IR (given the Trilangle program `?!oi@`) and plugged it into Godbolt, and this is what I see for main:

```
main:                                   # @main
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    _stack_ctor
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    _get_int
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    _print_int
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    _get_unichar
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    _print_unichar
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    _stack_dtor
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

Nothing I do seems to inline any of that. `_stack_dtor` is the most egregious, because its implementation is just

```c
inline void _stack_dtor(stack* self) {
  free(*self);
}
```

As can be confirmed by the assembly:

```
_stack_dtor:                            # @_stack_dtor
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rdi]
        jmp     free@PLT                        # TAILCALL
```

Some things I have tried that seem to not work, at least in Godbolt:

- Setting `-inline-threshold` and/or `-inlinehint-threshold` to a very high or very low value
- Replacing the `inlinehint` attribute with `alwaysinline` or `alwaysinline "nooutline"`
- Specifying an optimization level in the flags, e.g. `-O3`
- Removing `comdat` specifiers
- Changing the functions from `linkonce_odr dsolocal` to `private`
- Marking the functions `hot`

All of these seem to produce the same assembly (though `private` changes the label name): https://godbolt.org/z/hxj15dMnW

How do I make LLVM inline *anything*?

Comment: Interesting... I suspected that `_stack_dtor` *cannot* be inlined because it `jmp`s to `free@PLT` by tail call (in my view, inlining it requires that the call to `_stack_dtor` must be a tail call too, which is not satisfied in the call site). But changing it (`tail call` to simply `call`) and giving opt levels didn't work either.

Comment: I'll also note that `_stack_ctor` `tail call`s `calloc`, but the emitted assembly definitely doesn't have a tail call there. Similarly, `_stack_pop`, `tail call`s `llvm.assume`, which doesn't make any sense if interpreted literally.

Comment: Have you tried running `opt` manually with inline and always_inline passes? Also, mark the functions as always_inline.

Comment: @SK-logic Admittedly no, but I'm not even sure I have that installed, given that I _only_ have `clang` and not a standalone `llc` on my machine. Clang can still compile and link LLVM IR, so I haven't had any major problems with that.

Comment: how do you produce LLVM IR then if you don't have the libraries?

Comment: `clang -emit-llvm` works well enough.

Comment: I mean, how do you produce IR from your compiler, if you're not using llvm libraries directly? If it's in a text form, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @SK-logic I am generating it in text format: https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/blob/a62939e052830516c788467d4926bfef62c69189/llvm/README.md I figured that would make it easier to see what it's doing in case something goes wrong.

Comment: LLVM IR change too often, and it's always recommended to construct it using the API. You can always dump it in a text form later if you want to debug it. If you're using a language that does not do C++ interop well, there is an `llvm-c` layer that is more than enough for constructing all the IR features and is bindable to virtually anything.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `clang` instead of `llc`

Clang can handle LLVM IR files, though you may need to use the `-xir` flag for it to recognize them as such. When using clang, any optimization level besides `-O0` causes inlining to occur: https://godbolt.org/z/6PvGezPsP

I'm still unsure as to *why* `llc` doesn't inline anything, but at least this serves as a workaround.